# Visual studio emulator doesn't connect when used in VPN

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, vpn, visual-studio-2012

Hi I'm trying to access internet in emulator when I'm connected to vpn using Cisco system vpn client.

I followed [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff754351%28v=vs.92%29.aspx#BKMK_DisableProxy)
but couldn't get much help.
I'm using Windows8 release preview and visual studio 2012 rc.

**I'm able to connect to internet using desktop browsers**..

Comment: Emulator for what? Windows phone?

Comment: This could also be a proxy settings issue.  Can you access any internet from the Virtual Machine?  If so How?

Comment: I'm just accessing it through desktop...

Comment: I don't get it where does the emulator come in? So, Windows 8 is the virtual machine? Can you access the internet outside of the metro apps in windows 8?

Comment: I have installed windows 8 release preview. and yes I can access the internet outside of the metro style app.

Answer (score 1):

Referencing this [this guide](http://betterthaneveryone.com/archive/2008/08/31/getting-network-access-on-the-windows-mobile-emulator.aspx), it looks as though you probably have a bridged network configuration or have the device bound to your physical interface.  This would explain the behavior you described.

You want to have the virtual machine bound to the tunnel interface created by your VPN connection.  If there is a way to choose a NAT option in this dialog, try it.  This would be best as it takes whatever path to the internet your computer is configured to take and doesn't require a seperate IP address to be given to your VM from the VPN server.

Using this dialog select the Tunnel/Virtual/Not Physical interface created when you connect to VPN.

[image: settings page]

Good luck!

Comment: You are talking about win7 mobile emulator but my problem is related to windows 8 metro apps....

Comment: So, Windows 8 is the virtual machine?  Can you access the internet outside of the metro apps in windows 8?

Comment: @InderKumarRathore  The emulator allows the virtual machine (guest) to access the internet through one the hosts interfaces.  If this is not configured correctly, you will not have network access from the guest.

Answer (score 0):

you can ask your vpn administrator to give rights for accessing their internet to the user by which you are connecting VPN.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed our earlier it might be because your VPN is restricting your access to the internet. If so, a workaround would be to have your VPN administrator setup a remote desktop you could connect to through the VPN, then run the emulator on the remote desktop to connect to the internet.

Alternatively try to disable any antivirus/firewall suite you have installed to see if it blocks the emulator.

Comment: As I told earlier I can access internet through browser and is commenting on your answer.. but can't access it via metro style app..